# Are conformant array parameters VLAs?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, c11, variable-length-array

[CERT's Secure Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SEI+CERT+C+Coding+Standard) includes an item ([API05-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/API05-C.+Use+conformant+array+parameters)) which encourages the use of conformant array parameters, which is a recommendation I've implemented in a lot of my code (hidden behind [a macro](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/api-reference.html#HEDLEY_ARRAY_PARAM) for compilers which don't support them).

For those who don't know, a conformant array parameter is something like:

```
void foo(int length, char data[length]);
```

[API05-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/API05-C.+Use+conformant+array+parameters) provides more information.

Lots of compilers don't like variable-length arrays (for good reason). C11 demotes them from required (as they were in C99) to optional (compilers should define `__STDC_NO_VLA__` if they're not implemented). MSVC flat out doesn't support them. IAR hides them behind a switch (`--vla`). GCC and clang will warn you about them if you ask (with `-Wvla`, or `-Werror=vla` if you want an error).

Conformant array parameters don't suffer from the same problems as "normal" variable-length arrays; they don't result in variable stack usage. They just tell the compiler how big an existing array, which could be on the stack or heap, is.

My issue is that every compiler I'm aware of treats conformant array parameters as VLAs. This isn't such a big deal for compilers like MSVC since I can just define my macro to nothing, but for compilers like GCC and clang I want to use conformant array parameters but don't want to trigger `-Wvla` diagnostics.

According to API05-C (emphasis added):

> Consequently, an array declaration that serves as a function argument may have an index that is a variable or an expression. **The array argument is demoted to a pointer and is consequently not a variable length array (VLA).** Conformant array parameters can be used by developers to indicate the expected bounds of the array. This information may be used by compilers, or it may be ignored. However, such declarations are useful to developers because they serve to document relationships between array sizes and pointers. This information can also be used by static analysis tools to diagnose potential defects.

I desperately want this to be true, but I can't seem to find the relevant parts of the [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) or [C11](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) standards.

So, based strictly on the C99/C11 standards, are conformant array parameters VLAs? Or, to put it another way, does passing an array as an argument really demote it to a pointer?

Obviously, please cite the relevant parts of the specification(s).

Comment: If I understand your question, and you are asking about a function like `type funcname (int a, int array[a]) { ... }`, then yes, `array` is a VLA (it can't be anything else by definition, `'a'` is not a constant). Also, you may prefer [C11 Standard (n1570 draft)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) over the *.pdf* form.

Comment: `does passing an array as an argument really demote it to a pointer?` Yes. It would be pretty heavy not to do so.

Comment: David: Yes, that's what I'm asking; edited to make that clearer. As I mentioned (and Alceste_ alluded to), it's not clear that it's actually an array, in which case it can't very well be a variable length array.

Comment: Alceste_: the question here isn't how it's implemented by the compiler, but rather how the C spec handles it.

Comment: Examples aren't normative, but [Example 4 from 6.7.6.2p10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p10) calls `C` in the declaration `void fvla(int m, int C[m][m]);` a "VLA". The (normative) language in 6.7.6.2 indicates that yes, these array parameters are considered variable length arrays.

Comment: However, I think there's a difference between the colloquial usage of VLA and the standardese usage of the term (for example, `sizeof` doesn't work on these VLA parameters like it does with normal VLAs, because these VLA parameters are really just pointers).

Comment: @Cornstalks That's declared as a multidimensional array, that's different.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "every compiler I'm aware of treats conformant array parameters as VLAs"

Comment: @M.M: if you use a conformant array parameter in IAR, which doesn't support VLAs and defines `__STDC_NO_VLA__`, you will get an error (unless you pass `--vla` to enable them). GCC and clang will warn about CAPs if you pass `-Wvla`.

Comment: Hehe, Brian Kernighan's didn't like it, ["this botch is the biggest single problem with Pascal"](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html).  And around we go.  It is still a pointer at runtime, you just don't have to guess how large the array is.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a very sound CERT rule. It is IMO a huge mistake to make VLA optional in C11, because the main use of VLA is not actual array allocation, but rather pointers to VLA. It's a failure of the committee to understand how to write modern C such as `int (*ptr)[y] = malloc( sizeof( int[x][y] ) );` or indeed functions like these recommended by CERT.

Comment: @HansPassant: Pascal should have included a concept of "pointer to array of size computed at runtime", and perhaps "pointer to segment of array", but on the flip side C should have had a syntax that would indicate "pointer to *start* of an array" versus "pointer to some arbitrary element within an array".  Given e.g. `for (int i=0; i<100; i++) a[i] += b[i];`, a compiler could safely vectorize the loop if `a` and `b` each identify the start of an array, but not if `a` and `b` could point to different elements of the same array such that `b < a < b+100`.

Answer (score 1):

*All* parameters declared as array types are transformed to pointer types. VLAs are no exception.

N1256 (C99+TC1+TC2+TC3):

> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
>
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to type", where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

A function declared `void f(int a[10]);` takes any `int *`. A function declared `void f(int length, int array[length]);` takes an `int` and a `int *`.

However, you write:

> My issue is that every compiler I'm aware of treats conformant array parameters as VLAs. This isn't such a big deal for compilers like MSVC since I can just define my macro to nothing, but for compilers like GCC and clang I want to use conformant array parameters but don't want to trigger `-Wvla` diagnostics.

Well, it's tricky. It *is* a VLA before it is transformed to a pointer, and the point of `-Wvla` was to warn about code that would fail to compile on compilers that do not support VLAs. As you've seen, MSVC doesn't like the code.

> Conformant array parameters don't suffer from the same problems as "normal" variable-length arrays; they don't result in variable stack usage. They just tell the compiler how big an existing array, which could be on the stack or heap, is.

No, they do not do that. Given `void f(int a[10]);`, it is perfectly valid to call `f` with a null pointer, with a pointer to an array of length 1, etc. The compiler must support that. They only serve as a hint to human readers. The same applies to transformed VLAs.

Comment: Perhaps the question is also trying to ask whether an implementation that doesn't support VLA must allow the case of the subscript in the declarator being a non-constant expression

Comment: @M.M It's possible you're right, but I've re-read the question, and although I did find things I missed that I needed to include in my answer, I don't see that particular one.

Comment: I'm less interested in how compilers behave than how they *should* behave considering only the C standards. For example, does a compiler which supports C11 but not VLAs (and `__STDC_NO_VLA__` is defined) and fails to compile conformant array parameters still strictly conform to the standard?

Comment: @nemequ Okay. The function parameters are VLAs before the transformation to pointer types (directly from the definition of VLA), so if an implementation rejects them at that point, there doesn't appear to be anything in C11 to disallow such an implementation. Which makes sense: it wasn't valid C90, it became valid C99 because of the introduction of VLAs, but that C99 change became optional in C11 in its entirety.

Comment: @hvd: Would the Standard require that an implementation that doesn't support VLAs validate array arguments in parameter lists must ensure that the outermost dimension is either unspecified or constant, or could an implementation legitimately just ignore that dimension (since it won't affect program behavior in any case)?

Comment: @supercat Personally, I don't think it's any different from `void f(void p[10])` being an error even though `void f(void *p)` is valid: the function parameter array-to-pointer transformation requires the parameter to actually have a valid array type. On implementations that don't support VLAs, VLAs are not a valid array type.

Comment: @hvd: One of the design goals of C was to allow compilers to be as lightweight as possible while still being capable of producing decent code.  Requiring that compilers explicitly validate things they would otherwise have no reason to care about would seem to go against that goal.  Further, some compilers might internally be capable of supporting pointers to VLA types but not supporting automatic objects of such type; should compilers that can't support the latter be forbidden from supporting the former?

Comment: @supercat The example I presented is a case where compilers have been required to explicitly validate things they would otherwise have no reason to care about ever since C90. As for implementations supporting a subset of VLA functionality, they'll just have to claim not to support VLAs, they can still implement the required subset as an extension.

Comment: @hvd: If a compiler has parsed as far as `void f(int p[` and the next non-whitespace character isn't `]`, are there any cases where a valid non-VLA program would require doing anything other than gobbling tokens until the number of `]` tokens exceeds the number of `[` tokens, and then behaving as though there had been a `*` before the type?  I know qualifiers like `restrict` go in the `[]`, but are there any cases where processing of such directives would be required to achieve the right semantics (as opposed to merely facilitating optimizations)?

Answer (score 1):

They are not VLA, but just pointers. If you extend that rule to more than one dimension you  obtain a variably modified type, VM, still not a VLA.

If you want to indicate that the pointer should not be 0, there is `static` as in

```
void Toto(size_t n, double vec [static n]);
```

which indicates that `vec` must have at least `n` elements, and in particular can't be null.

Comment: So, to be clear, if a compiler which supports C11 but not VLAs (and defines `__STDC_NO_VLA__`) and fails to compile conformant array parameters, it does not conform to the the C11 standard?

Comment: The standard seems to me to be fairly clear that the declarator has a  VLA type before being adjusted to pointer type

Comment: @nemequ, theoretically, yes, but I don't think that such a compiler exists.

Comment: IAR. It behaves exactly like that unless you pass --vla.