# How to pass the number of elements of an array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, average

I would like to pass a n number of elements part of an array to a function in order to calculate the average. 
Essentialy i would like to keep the number of elements dynamic in the code so that a custom number can be entered.

```
float average(float num[]); 

int main() 
{ 
  int n,i,k; 
  float num[n]; 
  printf("Enter the numbers of elements: "); 
  scanf("%d",&k);
  for(i = 0; i < k; ++i)
  {
    printf("%d. value: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &num[i]);
  }
  printf("Average = %.2lf",average(num)); 
  return 0;
}

float average(float num[])
{
  int i,n;
  float sum = 0.0, avg;
  n = sizeof(num)/sizeof(int);

  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    sum += num[i];
  }
  avg = sum / n;
  return avg;
}
```

the `n = sizeof(num)/sizeof(int);` is somehow not passing the correct number of elements. 
I tried to dig around on the web and tried different options but nothing seem work correctly. 
I guess this is because I am not passing the array to a function correctly.. but  do not know how, please advise, many thanks

Comment: How is it possible to declare an “array of size n”, when n is undefined? That’s now how valid C array declarations work. Also, enable  compiler warnings..

Comment: as user2864740 pointed out, C doesn't have dynamic arrays. Arrays are allocated at compile time, not at run time. You can use another approach and allocate memory yourself at run time, but not with an array declaration.

Comment: "How to pass the number of elements of an array to a function" Well, how do you pass any other argument to a function? If you have the size, then just pass it as any other argument?

Comment: Note that in function `float average(float num[])` the `sizeof(num)` is the size of the pointer that `num` decays to. Nothing is known about the array except the type. You must pass the number of elements as another parameter.

Comment: 'float num[n];' is useless, because `n` is not initialized -> it has no relationship with the user input `k` at all.

Comment: Some people need to read up on the almost 20 years old C99 standard.  Granted, `n` needs to be initialized, but, if `n` is an integer and is initialized to a non-negative value that isn't too big, `float arr[n];` is valid C — and has been for a very long time (even if some major C compilers _still_ don't recognize it).

Comment: I think i work it out.. the number of elements also should be passed to the function:

float average(float num[],int k) ?
it seem working this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *main*

> ```
>   float num[n];
> ```

must be moved under because *n* is not initialized, so :

> ```
>  int n,i,k; 
>  float num[n]; 
>  printf("Enter the numbers of elements: "); 
>  scanf("%d",&k);
> ```

must be like

```
 int i,k; 

 printf("Enter the numbers of elements: "); 
 if (scanf("%d",&k) != 1) {
   puts("invalid size");
   return -1;
 }
 float num[k];
```

In *average* :

> ```
> n = sizeof(num)/sizeof(int);
> ```

is wrong because the number of elements in *num* is unknown, so `sizeof(num)` values the size of a pointer, you need to give the number of element in parameter

```
 float average(float num[], int n);
```

and in *main*

```
printf("Average = %.2lf",average(num, k));
```

and

```
float average(float num[], int n)
{
  int i;
  float sum = 0.0;

  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    sum += num[i];
  }

  return sum / n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array as a function parameter in C, it is "adjusted" to a pointer.  In C11, it's § 6.7.6.3 ¶ 7:

> A declaration of a parameter as "array of *type*" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to *type*", where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the **[** and **]** of the array type derivation. If the keyword **static** also appears within the **[** and **]** of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

That said, you can inform the compiler and/or additional tooling (like static analysis tools) that another parameter carries the length, but that parameter has to come *before* the array parameter.  It's a good practice to get into; see [API05-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/API05-C.+Use+conformant+array+parameters) from the *SEI CERT C Coding Standard* for a bit more information.

The problem is that compilers kind of suck at it.  First, conformant array parameters are only allowed in C ≥ C99, so if your code is supposed to be strictly C89 or something they won't work.

Even though conformant array parameters are (debatably) [not variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962479/are-conformant-array-parameters-vlas), most compilers basically treat them as such, and compiler support for VLAs is pretty spotty; C11 even makes support for VLAs optional.  MSVC doesn't implement them at all.  GCC and Clang (at least) will warn if you use them with `-Wvla` enabled.  PGI has a bug which causes causes compilation to fail.  IAR also treats them as VLAs, and emits a warning if you don't enable variable-length arrays (support is off by default, but there is a command line switch to enable them).  Tiny C Compiler also emits an error; IIRC because it also thinks of them as VLAs.

That said, I still like to use them.  It makes the code easier to understand, and smart static analysis tools can make use of them to better check your code.  If you want to make your code portable, though, you'll want to hide it behind a macro like [the one I have in Hedley](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/api-reference.html#HEDLEY_ARRAY_PARAM).

Whether or not you want to use conformant array parameters, you'll need to modify your code.  You can either pass arrays as two arguments or create a type that encapsulates both the length and the array… two arguments is definitely the idiomatic solution.  So for your prototype you would end up with something like

```
// No conformant array parameters, just another parameter
float average(size_t n, float num[]);
// CAP
float average(size_t n, float num[n]);
// CAP with a macro
float average(size_t n, float num[ARRAY_PARAM(n)]);
```

`sizeof(num)` will still be equal to `sizeof(float*)` (since that's what it is), but at least you know how many elements are in the array.