# Is GCC right about this being a VLA?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99

This question is quite similar to "[Are conformant array parameters VLAs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962479/are-conformant-array-parameters-vlas)", with the only difference being that here I'm using the `static` keyword within the `[` and `]` of the array declaration (introduced in C99), meaning that the declared array should have space for at least `len` elements. Here's an example:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(size_t len, const int arr[static len]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    const int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    print_array(sizeof arr / sizeof *arr, arr);
    return 0;
}
```

This code when compiled with the `-Wvla` flag on both GCC and Clang gives the following warning:

```
main.c:4:1: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘arr’ [-Wvla]
    4 | void print_array(size_t len, const int arr[static len]) {
      | ^~~~
```

What would be the point in `arr` being a VLA even when specifying `static`? Wouldn't this make `static` useless for cases like this?

I tried looking for an answer in the C standard, but I was unable to find one.

Thanks!

Comment: VLA's, including `static len` syntax, was added in the C99 standard. You build with the C90 standard. Add the option `-std=c99` (or `-std=c11` for the C11 standard) when building.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe they *are* compiling with C11 (but with [`-Wvla`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wvla) enabled): https://godbolt.org/z/d4j193a1M

Comment: As for why `static len` might be needed, what if the called uses an invalid `len` argument? Taking your example, what if the function was called as `print_array(32, arr)`? Who knows what some code might actually do, and what length might actually be passed?

Comment: And Tachi, please [edit] your question to show us how you actually build your [mre].

Comment: Don't compile with the `-Wvla` flag, problem solved? C11 as such doesn't have much to do with this since all these features were introduced in C99.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry, I for some reason remembered that `static len` has been introduced in C11. Thanks for bringing it up! In any case, I believe the main point of the question still stands. Editing now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and no, I'm not using C90 for building, it's just that GCC's message is misleading.

Comment: The `-Wvla` is a miss-designed flag. The original purpose was detection of VLA objects allocated on stack but it was implemented to detect all declarations of VLA *types*.

Comment: @tstanisl that definitely added to the confusion here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is GCC right about this being a VLA?

C 2018 (and C 2011) 6.7.6.2 4 says, of array declarators:

> … If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a *variable length array* type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

In the declaration `const int arr[static len]`, `len` is not an integer constant expression, so the array type is a variable length array type. So GCC is correct.

> What would be the point in `arr` being a VLA even when specifying static?

6.7.6.3 7 says:

> … If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

An example of how a compiler could use this is that, if the body of the function contains an evaluated expression `arr[i]`, where `arr` has been declared with `const int array[static len]`, the compiler may presume `i` < `len`, and it could make optimizations based on that.

> Wouldn't this make `static` useless for cases like this?

No, although it would not surprise me if a compiler does not take advantage of this information.

Comment: Does `arr` being a VLA has some meaningful impact in practice, apart from making code incompatible with MSVC? Thanks for the answer, by the way :)

Comment: In any case, I find `arr` being a VLA a bit unfortunate, since it significantly limits `static`'s usefulness (as VLAs are an optional feature)... I really don't see why the standard committee decided that it should be a VLA in this case.

Comment: @Tachi "Does arr being a VLA has some meaningful impact in practice". Yes, but for multidimensional arrays. For example `void foo(int n, int A[n][n])` will let one use `A[i][j]` inside the function.

Comment: Re: "compiler does not take advantage": Clang does take advantage of `static` and figures out that, for example, [`arr != 0` is true](https://godbolt.org/z/TKqfcKc6j). GCC doesn't. Re: "compiler may presume `i < len`": can you provide an example featuring `arr[i]` and `len`?